# using python keyring on app used across multiple devices

Tags: python, credentials, python-keyring

I am looking for a way to share my app with my coworkers without giving them the credentials for the database that the app accesses.  I found keyring (https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) and thought that this might be a solution to this issue.  What I'm not sure of is how I can share this across multiple devices.  It seems keyring saves this data in the OS.  Does that now mean that I can't use this in the way that I'd like to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish an app for others to use, you should look into environment variables on the platform that you're hosting the app on.

That's where you'll store any credentials, accessing them from your Python application will depend on what platform you're using but there will be documentation on how to do that on your platforms docs.

Comment: I am just packing this code with pyinstaller and distributing to a handful of people within my organization.  I do not intend to publish the app beyond that.